# How to avoid: read.table truncates numeric values beginning with 0

Tags: r, import, read.table, zero-padding

I want to import a table (`.txt` file) in R with `read.table()`. One column in my table is an ID with nine numerals - some ids begin with a 0, other with 1 or 2.

R truncates the first 0 (012345678 becomes 12345678) which leads to problems when using this ID to merge another table.

Can someone give me a hint how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As said in Ben's answer, `colClasses` is the easier way to do it. Here is an example:

```
read.table(text = 'col1 col2
           0012 0001245',
           head=T,
           colClasses=c('character','numeric'))

  col1 col2
1 0012 1245      ## col1 keep 00 but not col2
```

Comment: cool I did not know about colClasses strange how setting ```as.is=T``` did not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

A reproducible example would be nice, but: use the `colClasses` argument to `read.table()` to specify that you want this column to be read as a `character` variable, not `numeric`.  Or make them back into `character` variables after reading them in, using `sprintf` to pad the numbers with leading zeros.  (The former is probably easier.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a for loop to add leading zeros to rows based on a condition. Although this is a post-hoc solution (adding leading 0's *after* reading the table), it worked for me so thought I'd share:

Let's take the example of a column of zip codes. All values should contain 5 digits (e.g. 01234), but R removes leading zeros (so '01234' becomes '1234'). You can add a trailing zero to all cells that contain only 4 characters with this code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(nchar(df$zipCode[i])<5){
    df$zipCode[i]<- paste0('0',df$zipCode[i])
  }
}
```