# How to convert a integer 123033 to time 12:30:33 format in R

Tags: r, dataframe

After I imported the text file into R, R omitted "0" in the time column.

For example:

```
Before import time | After import time
077250             | 77250
000002             |     2
```

Thus, unable to convert to the correct time format. (from 77250 to 07:25:50)

How can i convert the integer time to the correct time format?

I have tried:

```
chron (time, "%H:%M:%S")
strptime(time, "%H:%M:%S")
time <- as.hms(time)
```

Comment: How did you read the file? That's a string, not an integer. You should modify your import code to treat that field as a string

Comment: I uses , read.delim method to import the text file... how can i import code to treat the field as a string?

Comment: @momoni post your code in the question itself.

Comment: @momoni in any case, `read.delim` is an alias for `read.table`. You can use the `as.is` parameter to prevent the conversion of text fields to numbers or factors. You can pass the column classes through `colClasses`

Comment: Related, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14854485/680068

Comment: @Ronak Shah yes! sorry about that. Im intending to convert 072550 to 07:25:50 (HH:MM:SS) format

Comment: @momoni Check the second duplicate. You could load the string as a `Date` directly. The reason `read.csv(con, colClasses=c('numeric','myDate'), header=FALSE)` works even though `read.csv` isn't supposted to have a `colClasses` parameter is that any extra parameters are passed to the underlying `read.table` call directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str_pad` from the `stringr` package to restore the zeroes:

```
library(stringr)
time_old <- "2"
time_new <- str_pad(time_old, width = 6, side = "left", pad = 0)
```

Then, you should be able to use the `chron` function:

```
chron::chron(times = time_new, format = list(times = "hms"),
             out.format = "h:m:s")
[1] 00:00:02
```

Comment: Hi @cettt , thanks for your reply !! As, i have a few dataset has to go through this process and time colomn is actually in a dataframe X1. how can i change it for that X[i]$time column which it goes in a loop. so that it can be used for dataset X2 X3 X4..

Answer (score 3):

We can use `sprintf` and `strptime`/`as.POSIXct`

If you have read them as numeric use `%d` in `sprintf` or use `%s` if they are characters.

```
x <- c(072550, 2)
format(strptime(sprintf("%06d", x), "%H%M%S"), "%T")
#[1] "07:25:50" "00:00:02"

x <- c("072550", "2")
format(strptime(sprintf("%06s", x), "%H%M%S"), "%T")
#[1] "07:25:50" "00:00:02"
```

Answer (score 1):

[This possibly duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022299/specify-custom-date-format-for-colclasses-argument-in-read-table-read-csv) shows how to read the data in the format you want directly, by specifying your own formatting function through `colClasses` :

```
setAs("character","myDate", function(from) as.Date(from, format="%Y%m%d") )
setAs("character","myTime", function(from) chron(times = from, format = "hms", out.format = "h:m:s"))

tmp <- c("1\t20080815\t072550", "2\t20100523\t000002")
con <- textConnection(tmp)

tmp2 <- read.delim(con, colClasses=c('numeric','myDate','myTime'), header=FALSE)
```

`tmp2` contains :

```
  V1         V2       V3
1  1 2008-08-15 07:25:50
2  2 2010-05-23 00:00:02
```

`read.delim` is a shortcut for `read.table` that sets a few defaults and passes any extra parameters like `colClasses` directly to `read.table`